# What does happen to the DB when implementing autoscaling on EC2 (AWS)

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, autoscaling

I want to implement autoscaling on my EC2 (AWS) but looks like I've arrived to a dead end...

I explain myself: right now I'm not using RDS, so both, the application and the DB are in my EC2, what would happen if I implement autoscaling on this scenario? How are the new instances going to interact with my DB? As far as I know, the new instances are like clones of the original one, so does this mean that there'll be clones of the original DB?

Should I migrate my DB to RDS before anything?

Autoscaling in general and on AWS in particular is something new to me so forgive me if this is a silly question...

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put your database on your autoscaling instances - you would need to use RDS or Dynamodb (or any other database), that does not live on temporary instances.

If you definitely want to run your own db instance, it should be on an instance that is not part of your autoscaling group and all of the other instances would talk to it.